# Delete and recreate a VM in Azure

Tags: azure

I want to move my Azure VMs to a new azure network.

I've created a new Network as I need it to be. If I delete the VMs can I just make new ones from their vhd's and specify the new network as I create them?

I looked at creating an image from a test vhd but Azure wants me to tick to say I've sysprep'd the machine, which I havent (and dont want to).

I really just want to have exactly the same machine but in a different network..

Thanks very much for any help!

p.s someone's marked this as an unhelpful post, do let me know why. I've looked all over for and answer to this.

Comment: what do you mean by different azure network? Is it a different azure account?

Comment: A different Azure Virtual Network. I made a new one in Azure and want to move the VMs to that

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

The scenario you describe is absolutely possible. Just shutdown the VM first. Then delete it. Then create a VM using the orphaned VHD and point it to the new VNet. That shall work!